# php script doesn’t work well when called from html (raspberry pi)

Tags: php, html, jquery, linux, raspberry-pi

I am creating a web page on a raspberry pi

Here is the essence of my html code:

```
<html><head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
        $("#test").load('climate.php') //load php result on the page
        }, 1000);
    });

</script>
</head>

<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
    <div id="test"></div>
</body></html>
```

I want to include some data from a text file using this php script :

```
<?php
    $filename = "/var/tmp/climate/save_climate.txt";
    if(file_exists($filename)){
      echo file_get_contents($filename);
    }
    else {
      echo 'could not find file'
    }
?>
```

My html and my php scripts work well, but there is an issue with the access to the file:

When I test my PHP script, he finds my file:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/HTML/home $ PHP climate.php
Temp=20.0*  Humidity=64.0%
```

But on the web page, this doesn’t work:

my **'could not find file'** message is displayed.

Is there someone with an explanation of what is happening here?

Thank you in advance!

Precisions:

- both my php script and my html are located in /var/www/html/home
- the text file is in /var/tmp/climate/save_climate.txt . He is updated every 10 min by cron, this is why he is not in the same directory.
- my website and my php script work well, the issue comes from somewhere else.
- my website is on a local network, completely hosted by my raspi.
- I’m on raspbian Buster

Comment: where are you storing the files for apache to read them ?

Comment: what url are you using ?

Comment: ist it `html` or `HTML`. Linux filepaths are case sensitive afaik

Comment: all is lowercase, my website works well, this is the only issue